# Проблемы с импортированием файлов библиотеки unirest. Не могу их физически найти

Tags: java

У меня проблемы с импортом библиотеки unirest. 
[Пример кода](http://pastebin.com/7yWpnf2p). Я успешно импортировал библиотеку, но у меня проблемы с файлом у которого пакет "com.mashape.unirest.http", он не имеет следующих файлов:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.CloseableHttpAsyncClient;
```

Без понятия что делать, т.к. я искал эти файлы через гугл и через яндекс около 30 минут, но так и не нашел ответа. не могу их физически найти. 
Хелп.

Comment: Вы подключили библиотеку, но не подключили зависимости. [Вот они](http://unirest.io/java.html), перечислены в документации. Это все должно быть в classppath. Вы используете систему сборки?

Comment: Скачал по нижеприведенной ссылке нажав: "Download ZIP".
https://github.com/Mashape/unirest-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/mashape/unirest/http
enzo, касаемо системы сборки не понял, так что не использую. Я новичок. Wial, как подтянуть зависимости? Куда написать этот код и как запустить? Как я понимаю это не java, а xml. Но что с этим делать?

Comment: Импортировал unirest-java-1.4.9 по ссылке ниже:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051991/importing-jar-file-into-intellij-idea
Проблема актуальна. Help plz

Comment: intellij idea Maven getting started - создаете проект maven, копируете зависимость, обновляете.

Comment: Это разве не оно https://hc.apache.org/?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему, вы просто скачали эту библиотеку в виде jar файла, однако эта библиотека тянет за собой несколько транзитивных зависимостей ( которые в свою очередь тянут свои).

Вы можете посмотреть на них в секции: Compile Dependencies по ссылке.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mashape.unirest/unirest-java/1.4.9

И даже скачать, но это я делать не советую. Советую изучить maven https://maven.apache.org/

Простейший скрипт (pom.xml), который подтянет все зависимости:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>id</groupId>
   <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
   <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>

   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
      <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.9</version>
     </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```